# Error in my code?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtable

I'm creating an application that has a login page, asks user to enter details. The user can view his/her entered details, and an admin can see all the details entered. i'm using MYSQL for this and using NetBeans to create the required forms.

Now, I wanted to import data into tables in my forms from a database, called tenderdetails with a table calldetails. I made datatypes of three of the fields as BLOB initially. On importing data, I was getting junk values in these fields.

So, i tried changing datatype of these fields to TEXT. This throws exceptions. Something like this (Issue is a field, AAI package)

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException Exception Description: The object [DATA THAT I ENTERED FOR FIELD ISSUE], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[issue-->tenderdetails.calldetails.Issue]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(AAI.Calldetails --> [DatabaseTable(tenderdetails.calldetails)])], could not be converted to [class [B]. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
```

and

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException Exception Description: The object [DATA THAT I ENTERED FOR FIELD ISSUE ], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[issue-->tenderdetails.calldetails.Issue]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(AAI.Calldetails --> [DatabaseTable(tenderdetails.calldetails)])], could not be converted to [class [B].
```

and also,

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException Exception Description: The object [DATA THAT I ENTERED FOR FIELD ISSUE ], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[issue-->tenderdetails.calldetails.Issue]] with descriptor [RelationalDescriptor(AAI.Calldetails --> [DatabaseTable(tenderdetails.calldetails)])], could not be converted to [class [B]. at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.couldNotBeConverted(ConversionException.java:75) at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper.buildBytesFromHexString(Helper.java:265)
```

These exceptions are again removed when I use the datatype BLOB for these fields. When I changed this datatype to VARCHAR, the exceptions were still thrown.

Even if I use TEXT and don't display those three fields, no exceptions are seen.

This thing also affects another part of my code. I'm transferring the data in jTable to Excel. Of course on using blob, the junk value gets transferred into the Excel file. On using TEXT, the "\n" somehow messes up in my code and new lines are given to the same record, so that the whole symmetry gets messed up. On using BLOB, the symmetry is absolutely fine.

I saw somewhere online that sometimes this junk value means something actually, so for reference, I get this:

```
[B@5c1b24db
[B@deae877
[B@77e427db
[B@6351149e
[B@7191f56d
[B@7c59b580
```

So, what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: That _junk_ you are referring to is `hashcode`!!

Comment: The `toString()` method.

Comment: So what do I do to solve it?
I used the Issue as String in my Java code.

Comment: If you post your EclipseLink mapping files or your annotated class we can be of more help.

Comment: I'm new to Java, and basically added my MYSQL database (tenderdetails), which added the following: EclipseLink (JPA 2.1):eclipselink.jar; javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar; org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b.jar. Is that any help?

Answer (score 1):

This error is also thrown if you accidentally annotate an entity relationship with `@Basic`.

Answer (score -1):

A common issue. You are persisting the `toString()` value of your Java object rather than it's serialized form.

In order to persist serialized objects into a database you need to use the Java serialization framework.

If you use a `BLOB` datatype then you need to write the bytes of an `ObjectOutputStream` to the `BLOB`, something like this:

```
    final Object thing = new Object();

    try (final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(blob.setBinaryStream(1))) {
        oos.writeObject(thing);
    }

    final Object myNewThing;
    try(final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream())) {
        myNewThing = ois.readObject();
    }
```

From your exception is seems that you are using EclipseLink to save data to MySQL. If this is the case then you should be able the map the field as a `serializable` datatype and EclipseLink will handle the serialization/deserialization for you.

Comment: Actually, I don't know a thing about Serialization. Was just reading up on it.
Pretty new to Java.

Comment: Can you explain the code you've written above? Say, I have the field issue, as I said above... how can I implement serialization using the code you wrote?